# how to get a dynamic form id generated by jsp in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

How to get a formId that is generated by using a jsp using jquery?

```
<c:url var="updateSubUserDetails" value="/employer/recruiters/updateSubUserDetails"/>
<form id="updateform${subUser.employerId}" action="${updateSubUserDetails}"  method="post" >
  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden" name="subUserId" value="${subUser.employerId}"/>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" id="subUserName${subUser.employerId}" name="subUserName" class="form-control "  value="${subUser.firstName}" placeholder="Edit Sub User Name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text"  id="subUserEmail${subUser.employerId}" name="subUserEmail" class="form-control "  value="${subUser.emailId}" onchange="checkMail(${subUser.employerId})"    placeholder="Edit Email"/>
    </div>
      <span id="avialabilityMessage${subUser.employerId}"></span>  
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" id="subUserMobile${subUser.employerId}" name="subUserMobile" class="form-control "  value="${subUser.mobileNumber}"placeholder="Edit Contact No"/>
    </div>
    <sec:csrfInput/>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <input type="button" id="muEditButtonID" onclick="updateSubUserDetails(${subUser.employerId})" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" value="Update"> 
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

How to get above dynamically generated form id in javascript jquery? Please assist me.

Comment: Do you want it in `updateSubUserDetails` function?

Comment: `document.querySelector('[id^="updateform"]')`?

Comment: Improved code formatting.

Comment: Please post whatever code you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

```
//if you sure there is only one form
document.forms[0]
//else
document.querySelector('[id^="updateform"]')
```

so, if you want to get id just add .id

```
//if you sure there is only one form
document.forms[0].id
//else
document.querySelector('[id^="updateform"]').id
```

Comment: I have multiple forms with different ids like ex: updateform120 , updateform121 .....etc how can i get that dynamically generated formId.

Comment: you need to get id's of all forms, or just one? Or you want to get form element by id?

document.querySelectorAll('[id^="updateform"]')  - this will return you set of nodeElements with  id's, as you described above.

Comment: how can i get actual formId in that all the listOfFormIds

Comment: this wil give you array of all id's

`var forms = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="updateform"]'),
ids = [];
for(var i =0; i < forms.length; i++){
ids.push(forms[i].id)
}
console.log(ids); // [ 'formid1',formid2','formid3']`

Comment: how can i get (i am going to submit) particular formId in that listOfIds

Comment: if you want to submit it, you just dont need that list, if i correct understood you; try this

`document.getElementById('updateform' + ${id}).submit();`

where ${id} - is your id you want to submit

Comment: ${id} also i want to get dynamically

Comment: $(document).on("submit","#jsloginform", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 var emailId=$("#emailId").val();
 var password=$("#password").val();
 var data = $("#jsloginform").serialize();
 var action=$("#jsloginform").attr("action");
 var type=$("#jsloginform").attr("method");
    $.ajax({
      type :  type,   
   url :  action,
   data :  data,
   success: function(response){
        
 });   
});

Comment: Do you want to add submit event listener to all forms with that id?